# How do i get the tagGuid given the tag name?

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa-touch, evernote

**`EverNote sdk :`**

Wanted to know if there is a method to get the `tagGuids` from the `tagName`.
For instance the tag name is `ShoppingList` whats the corresponding `tagGuids`.

[image]

Need to fill the **TODO:**

```
// TODO: Given the tag name, get the  tagGuid here.

EDAMNoteFilter* filter = [[EDAMNoteFilter alloc] initWithOrder:0 ascending:NO words:nil notebookGuid:nil tagGuids:nil timeZone:nil inactive:NO emphasized:nil];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer

```
 [[EvernoteNoteStore noteStore] listTagsWithSuccess:^(NSArray *tags) {
                for(EDAMTag *tag in tags)
                {
                    if([tag.name isEqualToString:@"ShoppingList"])
                    {
                         EDAMNoteFilter* filter = [[EDAMNoteFilter alloc] initWithOrder:0 ascending:NO words:nil notebookGuid:nil tagGuids:[@[tag.guid] mutableCopy] timeZone:nil inactive:NO emphasized:nil];
                    }

                    break;
                }
            } failure:^(NSError *error) {
                NSLog(@"tag error : %@",error);

            }];
```

Let me know if there is better way to do this.